# Singleton for MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, unity-game-engine, server, photon

Should i use singleton pattern for MongoDB. I'm currently building an Game Server for turnbase game using Photon Engine and MongoDB.

```
public sealed class GSEntities
{
    #region Fields
    public IMongoClient Client;
    public IMongoDatabase Database;

    private static GSEntities _instance;
    private static readonly Object sync = new object();

    public static GSEntities Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (sync)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                        _instance = new GSEntities();
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

It's good or should i use other pattern like Repository ?

Thanks for your helps ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's good or should i use other pattern like Repository ?

Generally speaking, you should use patterns *when you need them*. **Not** when you have the time, or it seems cool or it would not hurt.

So ask yourself, do you *need* a singleton? My guess is no. This could as well be a normal class that you happen to have only one instance of.

Do you *need* a repository pattern? My guess would be no as well. The description says:

> Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a collection-like interface for accessing domain objects.

Only you can decide. Again, *implement when needed*, **not** when you feel like it or others think it's cool.